# antlr4 empty alternative not working as expected

Tags: antlr4

I'd presumed that in general the rule

```
rule: ( something ? ) ;
```

could generally be expressed as alternation with nothing, with identical semantics

```
rule: ( something |  ) ;   <-- empty alt here
```

(provided of course 'something' is a single item or bracketed to make it so). It seems obviously correct but antlr4 isn't having it. This code does as I expect

```
version 1, works

opt_cursor_into_spec :
        ( cursor_into_spec ? )
    ;

cursor_into_spec :
        INTO
        sident ( COMMA sident ) *  
    ;
```

but this doesn't; failing to parse the input:

```
version 2, fails

opt_cursor_into_spec :   // this rule's changed
        cursor_into_spec
    |
        // empty alt
    ;

cursor_into_spec :       // this is the same
        INTO
        sident ( COMMA sident ) *
    ;
```

Here's part of the diagnostics trace on version 2, note the [***]

```
consume [@1,8:11='crsr',<483>,2:6] rule regular_ident
exit    regular_ident, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    sident, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    cic_cursor_name, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    cursor_ident_clause, LT(1)=<EOF>
enter   opt_cursor_into_spec, LT(1)=<EOF>
line 4:0 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'  [***]
exit    opt_cursor_into_spec, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    fetch_statement, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    sql_item, LT(1)=<EOF>
enter   opt_sql_separators, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    opt_sql_separators, LT(1)=<EOF>
exit    sql_items, LT(1)=<EOF>
```

This is odd as at *** it claims no viable alternative, but at the line before it says it's entered into opt_cursor_into_spec, but this rule has the empty alternative, which surely always matches - one can always match the empty string, I thought?

So is my assumption of this equivalence...

```
( x ? ) ===  ( x | <<<nothing>>> )
```

...incorrect, or what? 
This Q isn't about code, but about my understanding of semantics. If anyone thinks these should do the same, I'll try to post reproducible code.

---

---

Edit: More confused now. A stripped down grammar didn't reproduce. Something about the end of file was suspicious as the input to parse is just `fetch a` and it seems to get parsed in full according to the diagnostics trace, then fails. Hmm. I added an explicit EOF to the starting rule, so (a bit simplified)

```
sql_items : sql_item * ;  // ORIGINAL
```

became

```
sql_items : sql_item * EOF;  // NEW
```

And both (`x?` and `x|<<<nothing>>>`) suddenly work for NEW. Previously only x? worked for ORIGINAL.
Adding an EOF test should surely not cause a previously unsuccessful parse to succeed, can it?

---

---

Edit 3: edit 2 struck as it was misleading and unhelpful

<del>Edit 2: on reflection adding EOF to the grammar can of course cause a previously successful parse to fail, as an input can be well-formed at the start but malformed as a whole (ie. imagine parsing an expression `2 + 3 £$%&`, the start is valid but overall it's crud) but that's not apparently what's happening here.</del>

Answer (score 0):

In version 1, the rule `opt_cursor_into_spec` matches iff the rule `cursor_into_spec` matches.  In version 2, the rule `opt_cursor_into_spec` will always be matched. So the semantics of the grammar, specifically due to rules that have `opt_cursor_into_spec` as an element, will differ.

Likely, in version 2, you are getting a compile time warning about a rule that can match anything. You cannot ignore the warning unless you really understand the cause and effect.

Comment: Thanks, but I may be misunderstanding. Unfortunately I didn't post enough code to be clear but in V1 (and in V2 for that matter), cursor_into_spec is _not_ being used - the input I use deliberately does not invoke that rule. Also, you say "In V1...matches iff the rule `cursor_into_spec` matches" but surely `cursor_into_spec` doesn't need to match because of the ? following - it's optional - no match needed. If unclear I'll post some code to repro (you want?). FYI In V2 I'm getting no errors; I don't allow them.   Just to be clear, do you disagree with my equivalence at the bottom?

Comment: The equivalence is incorrect procedurally.  Antlr does not consider the rules as mere logical constructs. I traces a path through the rules.  If `cursor_into_spec` will never match, then v1 will never match; v2 will match since the empty alt will match without requiring anything to be consumed.

Comment: Even more confused now. To be clear by 'match' I mean 'to parse successfully/without error'. You say **If cursor_into_spec will never match, then v1 will never match** - but v1 is the successful code, and **v2 will match since the empty alt will match without requiring anything to be consumed** indeed, but V2 is failing - see the [***] bit in my post. OK, I'll try to get minimal code to repro.